# How to launch Flutter App from MainActivity.java

Tags: java, android, flutter, native

I have created app. I want to run app when device is restart\turned on. So I implemented the functionality in native code. Now the native code is calling the MainActivity class when device is restarted. Now I want to make a function in MainActivity which will launch my app. Something Like I call *main()* method of **main.dart** file from MainActivity.java.

If anybody know then kindly answer this question.

Answer (score 0):

Could you just create a Flutter project and add your native part in MainActivity.java?